# How to use this function within a PHP class?

Tags: php, serialization, gzip

```
class io_dz {
    /**
     * Compress
     */
    public static function Set($Data) {
        if ($Data) {
            $Out = addslashes(gzcompress(serialize($Data), 9));
        } else {
            $Out = FALSE;
        }

        return $Out;
    }

    /**
     * Decompress
     */
    public static function Get($Data) {
        if ($Data) {
            $Out = unserialize(gzuncompress(stripslashes($Data)));
        } else {
            $Out = FALSE;
        }
        return $Out;
    }
}
```

it's a simple compress before serialize function. How would I call this function and use it on `$data` 
I currently have:

```
$dataCompressor = new $io_dz();
$cdata = $dataCompressor->Set($data);
```

But it doesn't seem to work, any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared the method as static, you don't need to instanciate the object to access them.
Try only:

```
$cdata = io_dz::Set($data);
```

If you need more information about static method/attribute, you can check the PHP Manual that has quite a few easy to understand examples: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Answer (score 3):

`$cdata = $dataCompressor::Set($data);`

You need `::` because you made them static.  If they weren't static and were only public functions it would be `->`